# Time Format for DateTime field is not shown in the edit mode Asp Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Model I have the following :

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
public DateTime _time { get; set; }
```

In my `Edit` View in the Textbox the value that is set is the full **Date** and *time* and when ever i try manually to edit the value through the browser the jQuery Validations Yields an error that the date format is not correct

while I'm adding `ApplyFormatInEditMode=true` why in the textbox I'm getting the Full Date the the formated one (*only time*) and why the jQuery validator throw error when the format is time only without date and how can I by pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Html.EditorFor` and not `Html.TextBoxFor` if you want the custom format to be applied:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x._time)
```

Also by naming a property `_time` you are violating at least 2 C# naming conventions (property names start with an uppercase letter and not with an underscore).

Comment: Your answer is correct but do you know how to let jQuery validation understands that this is time field ?
and for the name its just an example

Comment: You will have to write a custom validation attribute for it implementing the `IClientValidatable` interface and a custom client side adapter to understand the custom format you have defined. But AFAIK there's nothing built into jQuery.validate that will validate a time for you. So you might need to add a custom validation method as well for this.